# How to solve SCRIPT1002: Syntax error <html lang="en"> on IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I can't find anything wrong with the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**The error**

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error    
create (2,1)
```

Here is the screenshots

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error must be due to other codes. Which kind of application are you running? Does it run well in other browsers? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? From the above inforamtion, we can't locate the issue.

Comment: yeah it is due to other codes, it is now fixed, thanks

Comment: If you like you can post the solution for this issue then mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.